# Date range selection from form then export CSV from MySQL data with selected range

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a database CSV export working fine,  but I want the user to be able to select a date range for the export process.

Here is my HTML part for the date select (format of date is `mm/dd/yyyy`):

```
<form action="csv_export_arp.php">
 <p>Select a date range from </p><label style="color:#FFF;" for="from">From</label>
 <input type="text" id="from" name="from" value="from" />
 <label style="color:#FFF;" for="to" >to</label>
 <input type="text" id="to" name="to" value="to"/>
 <input name="export" type="submit" value="Export Pending ARP CSV" />
</form>
```

My CSV export which works apart from the date range=

```
$sql_query = "SELECT ticket_number AS 'Ticket number', first_name AS 'First name', surname AS
'Last name', email AS 'Email address', product AS 'Product', retailer AS 'Retailer', dop AS 
'Date of purchase', message AS 'Message', address AS 'Postal address', DATE_FORMAT(created, 
 '%m/%d/%Y') AS 'Date created', status AS 'Status', action AS 'Action', comment AS 'Comment', 
 resolution AS 'Resolution' FROM $table WHERE status='Pending ARP'
 AND created >= DATE_FORMAT('from') AND created <  DATE_FORMAT('to')" ;
```

I am having trouble linking the values I get from the form (to and from) with the `WHERE` query for the date (status works fine), how can this be done? Any help much appreciated

```
 AND created >= DATE_FORMAT('from') AND created <  DATE_FORMAT('to')" ;
```

I feel this is the important line, how can I link this query in with my date range selections on the form?

**EDIT:**

This is the first part of the script:

```
<?php

$host = 'xxxxx'; // MYSQL database host adress
$db = 'wxxxxx'; // MYSQL database name
$user = 'xxxxx'; // Mysql Datbase user
$pass = 'xxxxxx'; // Mysql Datbase password
$from_data = $_POST['from']; //Should be sanitized before use in the query, or use PDO.
$to_data   = $_POST['to']; //Should be sanitized before use in the query, or use PDO. 
// Connect to the database
$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);

require 'scripts/exportcsv_arp.inc.php';

$table="support_users"; // this is the tablename that you want to export to csv from mysql.

exportMysqlToCsv($table);

?>
```

This the second part of the script (exportcsv_arp.inc.php)

```
<?php
function exportMysqlToCsv($table,$filename = 'export_arp.csv')
{
$csv_terminated = "\n";
$csv_separator = ",";
$csv_enclosed = '"';
$csv_escaped = "\\";
$sql_query = "SELECT ticket_number AS 'Ticket number', first_name AS 'First name', surname AS 'Last name', email AS 'Email address', product AS 'Product', retailer AS 'Retailer', dop AS 'Date of purchase', message AS 'Message', address AS 'Postal address', DATE_FORMAT(created, '%m/%d/%Y') AS 'Date created', status AS 'Status', action AS 'Action', comment AS 'Comment', resolution AS 'Resolution' FROM $table WHERE status='Pending ARP' created >= DATE_FORMAT('" . $from_data . "', '%d/%m/%Y') AND created <  DATE_FORMAT('" . $to_data . "', '%d/%m/%Y')" ;
// Gets the data from the database
$result = mysql_query($sql_query);
$fields_cnt = mysql_num_fields($result);
$schema_insert = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $fields_cnt; $i++)
{
    $l = $csv_enclosed . str_replace($csv_enclosed, $csv_escaped . $csv_enclosed,
        stripslashes(mysql_field_name($result, $i))) . $csv_enclosed;
    $schema_insert .= $l;
    $schema_insert .= $csv_separator;
} // end for
$out = trim(substr($schema_insert, 0, -1));
$out .= $csv_terminated;
// Format the data
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $schema_insert = '';
    for ($j = 0; $j < $fields_cnt; $j++)
    {
        if ($row[$j] == '0' || $row[$j] != '')
        {
            if ($csv_enclosed == '')
            {
                $schema_insert .= $row[$j];
            } else
            {
                $schema_insert .= $csv_enclosed .
                str_replace($csv_enclosed, $csv_escaped . $csv_enclosed, $row[$j]) . $csv_enclosed;
            }
        } else
        {
            $schema_insert .= '';
        }
        if ($j < $fields_cnt - 1)
        {
            $schema_insert .= $csv_separator;
        }
    } // end for
    $out .= $schema_insert;
    $out .= $csv_terminated;
} // end while
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($out));
// Output to browser with appropriate mime type, you choose ;)
//header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
//header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
echo $out;
exit;
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: What datatype are your date columns in the database?  what format do  the contents of this column take?

Comment: Hi Dave, the date is : %m/%d/%Y , any help on helping me get this working would be much appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

```
$from_data = $_POST['from']; //Should be sanitized before use in the query, or use PDO.
$to_data   = $_POST['to']; //Should be sanitized before use in the query, or use PDO.
```

And the part of the query which you pulled out should be

```
AND created >= DATE_FORMAT('" . $from_data . "', '%d/%m/%Y') AND created <  DATE_FORMAT('" . $to_data . "', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Many thanks, where does the " $from_data = $_post"code go at the top of you post, in relation to my form? the CSV query/script is on the file csv_export_arp.php.

Comment: Sorry bit trigger happy with the return key, see above

Comment: That is pulling in the data from the form, so it needs to go in the script which handles the form after submission.

Comment: Thanks again, I've edited my original question to include my two script files that, could you advise which file and where the code goes, may thanks.

Comment: So in the first part of the script, change `exportMysqlToCsv($table);` to `exportMysqlToCsv($table, $from_date, $to_date);` and in the second part, change `function exportMysqlToCsv($table,$filename = 'export_arp.csv')` to `function exportMysqlToCsv($table,$from_data,$to_data,$filename = 'export_arp.csv')`

Comment: thanks, but this didn't work , does the ` $from_data = $_POST['from']; //Should be sanitized before use in the query, or use PDO.
$to_data   = $_POST['to']; //Should be sanitized before use in the query, or use PDO.`  Not go anywhere now?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `exportMysqlToCsv($table, $from_data, $to_data);` instead of `exportMysqlToCsv($table, $from_date, $to_date);`

Comment: Hi ,many thanks again. still not wrking though. How is the date slections form the form been processed in the script? my csv files are just coming out blank. `$from_data = $_POST['from']; //Should be sanitized before use in the query, or use PDO.
$to_data   = $_POST['to']; //Should be sanitized before use in the query, or use PDO.` shouldn't this be included somewhere to tell the script what dates to use, sorry im a newb to this mysql php stuff